# Delete Query is rolled back automatically on azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a problem with executing delete statements on Azure SQL database with a large amount of data.

I am having a sales table with ~5 Million records on Azure SQL Database.

When I execute a stored procedure to delete all the data from this table, it executes for some time and then a new process is generated with new id and this the existing process starts to roll back and after the rollback when new process starts deleting the data then the new process again generates another process and start rollback and this same repetition continues forever.

At last, after many hours, the stored procedure fails and the data is not deleted.

I am having the Azure SQL Database with 100DTUs.

Does anybody know what may happen?

Comment: can you elaborate on this part `it executes for some time and then a new process is generated with new id and this the existing process starts to roll back and after the rollback when new process starts deleting the data then the new process again generates another process and start rollback and this same repetition continues forever` specifically what do you mean by process...did you get any errors during this..why cant you truncate when you are deleting whole table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete process may be reaching the limits of that tier. You can confirm that by running the following query while the delete process is running.

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

--service level objective (SLO) of 99.9% <= go to next tier

Hope this helps..

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're experiencing throttling. [You can read more about that he](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx)re. You can also check the [sys.event_log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database) to see if there are throttling events. The best solution would be to break up the delete into smaller chunks using some form of paging query.